# The program crashes when I try to access the contact from a phone using android studio

Tags: android

The program crashes when I use this line of code:

`Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tv);
        //textView.setText(Name);
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tv);
        //ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        String Name;
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                Name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                textView.setText(Name);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> --------- beginning of crash 07-28 15:01:42.622 2527-2527/com.example.mateusjose.contacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.mateusjose.contacts, PID: 2527
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mateusjose.contacts/com.example.mateusjose.contacts.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{5be2630 2527:com.example.mateusjose.contacts/u0a85}
>   (pid=2527, uid=10085) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) Caused
>   by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{5be2630 2527:com.example.mateusjose.contacts/u0a85}
>   (pid=2527, uid=10085) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636) at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4169)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5434)
>   at
>   android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2267)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1515)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:514) at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:472) at
>   com.example.mateusjose.contacts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: If the app crashes and you use Android Studio then there is a crash log (--> Android Monitor). Please share it!

Comment: Missing permission or you didn't request it of you are ANdroid 23+. Do as @0X0nosugar said, show the crash log

Comment: Add the crash log please. One can't help others without enough information

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this on manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

And for APIs 23+, you need to ask for user permission to access the contacts. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more details on how to ask.

Comment: Are you performing the query operations only after making sure the permission is granted?

Comment: no. Is there a way to grant this permission is run time?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the link on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use run time permissions and try.To find out if the issue is caused by run time permission, just go to app info in settings and check the permissions list.Turn contacts permission on if it is disabled.